# nunit3 inline runsettings args fail to parse on Mac

Tags: nunit-3.0, runsettings

please, can anyone tell what format should I use to pass runsettings args to test?
According to their example, it should be:

`dotnet test -- TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=\"<name>\", value=\"<value>\")`

but this way it ends with an error:

zsh: parse error near `)'

It looks like, it's a bug, but how come, that I can define such args in Rider and it works (I don't think, they create temporary .runsettings file)?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally, I found the answer [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/main/docs/RunSettingsArguments.md).

Format should be like this (for bash):

```
dotnet test -- TestRunParameters.Parameter\(name=\"myParam\",\ value=\"value\"\)
```